# What is "function f(a = {} = {} = {}) {}"

Tags: javascript, syntax

[image]

It won't throw syntax error. What does it mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a function which is using a [default parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters#:%7E:text=In%20JavaScript%2C%20function%20parameters%20default,value%20if%20they%20are%20undefined%20.) and [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

The first thing to note is that:

```
{x} = {x:1, y:2}
```

will evaluate to `{x:1, y:2}` while setting `x` to be `1`.

With that in mind your function does your operations in the following order, where each `{}` to the left of the `=` is destructuring syntax:

```
f(a = ({} = ({} = {})))
```

Above, we perform the most inner `{} = {}` first. This syntax is destructuring the empty `{}` object, so no variables are initialized, all it does is evaluate to an empty object `{}`. Now that that's evaluated, you can perform `{} = {}` again for the next set of parenthesis. This again just evaluates to `{}`.

Now that this is evaluated you evaluatively set `a = {}`, which sets the default parameter for `a`.

You can see this in action a little better by assigning the right-most object some properties and then destructuring those:

```js
function f(a = {z} = {x, y} = {x: 1, y: 2, z:3}) {
  console.log(a, x, y, z);
}
f();
```

Answer (score 0):

The default value of a is an empty object.

```
f();

function f(a = {} = {} = {}) 
{
    console.log(a);
}
```

Output:

```
Object {}
```